# Android App running on Emulator but crashes on real devices

Tags: java, android, firebase, apk

I have checked all the questions on stackoverflow regarding this question and have tried everything and still getting the same  error. I have an android application with firebase authentication, storage and database. The app is running on fine on every emulator that I create on android studio. I also tried running the app on devices created using Genymotion and the app works fine there too. Then I tried running on a real device using USB Debugging and even then the app runs fine.

The app crashed only when I try to install the app using the APK file created using Android studio "Build Apk" option. Since the app is running fine with USB debugging and on every emulator, I can't even see the error in logcat.

Here are file files.
Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kinny.instagram_clone">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.example.kinny.instagram_clone" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserList"
             />
        <activity android:name=".UserFeed"
            android:parentActivityName=".UserList"
            ></activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="504a079771b5c515a67b9ed577e080347a024bc7" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

My Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kinny.instagram_clone.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainPageLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="test@gmail.com"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LoginSignup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:onClick="signupOrLogin"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/changeButtonText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changeButtonText"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#1d27ff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and My main activity file

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener {

    // Layout elements
    EditText password;
    EditText email;
    TextView changeSingupLoginMode;
    Button signupButton;
    ImageView logo;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    EditText username;

    // Fierbase credentials
    public static FirebaseUser user;
    public static FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    public static DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
    DatabaseReference users;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    // Util variables
    Boolean signupModeActive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Write a message to the database


        signupModeActive = true;
        // Firebase Database reference
        users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        // Firebase Authentication
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in


                    makeToast("Welcome " + user.getEmail());
                    showUserList();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    makeToast("Welcome");
                }
            }
        };

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginSignup);
        logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainPageLogo);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        changeSingupLoginMode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeButtonText);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

        changeSingupLoginMode.setOnClickListener(this);
        logo.setOnKeyListener(this);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        email.setOnKeyListener(this);
        password.setOnKeyListener(this);
        username.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void showUserList() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserList.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    public void createAccount(final String accountEmail, final String accountPassword, final String accountUsername){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(accountEmail, accountPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            User newUser = new User(accountEmail, accountPassword, accountUsername);
                            myRef.push().setValue(newUser);
                            showUserList();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            task.getException();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void signupOrLogin(View view) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(email.getText()))) {
            this.makeToast("Please enter an email id!");
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(password.getText()))) {
            this.makeToast("Please enter a password");
            return;
        }

        if (!isValidEmail(String.valueOf(email.getText()))) {
            this.makeToast("Invalid email address!!");
            return;
        } else {

            if (signupModeActive) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(username.getText()))) {
                    this.makeToast("Please enter a username");
                    return;
                }

                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        boolean usernamTaken = false;
                        boolean emailIdTken = false;

                        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            if ((data.child("username").getValue()).equals(String.valueOf(username.getText()))) {
                                usernamTaken = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if(!usernamTaken){
                            createAccount(String.valueOf(email.getText()), String.valueOf(password.getText()), String.valueOf(username.getText()));
                            return;
                        }
                        else{
                            makeToast("Username Taken, Try Something else");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Log.w("data", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                    }
                });

            } else {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(String.valueOf(email.getText()), String.valueOf(password.getText()))
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Log.d("Login", "LogIn:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w("Login", "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    showUserList();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    public void makeToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.changeButtonText) {
            if (signupModeActive == true) {
                signupModeActive = false;
                changeSingupLoginMode.setText("Sign Up");
                signupButton.setText("Log In");
                username.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                signupModeActive = true;
                changeSingupLoginMode.setText("Log In");
                signupButton.setText("Sign Up");
                username.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.mainPageLogo || v.getId() == R.id.relativeLayout) {

            // removing keyboard form the app if clicked somewhere else

            InputMethodManager inm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            signupOrLogin(v);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please notice, that I also have multiple activities in my app, which can viewed [here](https://github.com/kinny94/instagram-clone/tree/master/instagram-clone2) .

Comment: You can see logcat on any device that's plugged in and has USB debugging enabled. You don't need to have deployed it via Android Studio.  In fact, you can see logcat for an attached device simply by running this command: `adb logcat`

Comment: @DougStevenson App is only crashing when I am trying to install with apk. When installing with USB debugging its working fine, so there are no errors in  logcat.

Answer (score 0):

1)If you plugged your device using usb and install apk and run it on your plugged device you could see logcat in Android Monitor panel in Android Studio 2) Also you could use Crashlytics(just attach it to your app) to see the errors in Crashlytics dashboard.